# Minimal voltage in linear accelerators to achieve relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, voltage, accelerator-physics

Could anyone tell me what is the minimal voltage between anode and cathode in a linear accelerators to achieve speeds where relativity starts to show?

Let me ask in a different way: "What is the minimal voltage scientists work with in linear accelerators?"

Comment: What is a "speed where relativity starts to show?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's just play an order of magnitude game.  Relativity should start to show up at kinetic energies approaching a particle's rest mass.  So, we have:

$$\begin{align}
qV &= mc^{2}\\
V &= \frac{mc^{2}}{q}
\end{align}$$

Using the values for the electron, we get about $5\times 10^{5}$ V for electrons to turn relativistic.  Protons are going to take longer, an anything heavier will take yet longer, since $m$ typically grows a lot faster than $q$.  If we want to get more precise than this, we are going to need to start talking precisions and things.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone tell me what is the minimal voltage between anode and cathode in a linear acellerators to achieve speeds where relativity starts to show?

Define the limits of *"starts to show"* that you care about.

Electrons are significantly relativistic at 100 kV and measurably so at a few 10s of kV.

> Let me ask in a different way: "What is the minimal voltage scientists work with in linear acelerators?"

Every CRT is linear accelerator, so the values go arbitrarily low, and nuclear physics is sometime done at a few tens of keV. It really depends on what you want to probe.